# In oracle plsql procedure can we use out parameter if our procedure has 'Pragma autonomous transaction'?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing a problem where in my package another package.procedure is called which has one IN parameter and one OUT parameter (number datatype).

Now this called procedure is declared as PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION and in execution block the OUT parameter is set to say `po_value := 1;`. After this there is some processing (in this we not setting OUT parameter anywhere) and finally in the EXCEPTION section, in WHEN OTHERS we setting OUT parameter to say `po_value := 0;`

I am doing some further processing with this OUT parameter in my calling  main procedure i.e `If po_value =1 then` some processing happens.

Here is my problem. Using Debugger I am passing some value to main proc and when it called another proc (as mentioned above) the OUT parameter value is shown as `NULL` in debugger's Smart Data tab. I am expecting it should either 1 or 0 and not NULL. So is `pragma autonomous_transaction`causing any problem (which I don't think should but as  I see no other reason I have doubts on it)?

Please suggest.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not telepathic and cannot visualise your situation from a verbal sketch. Please post some sample code which demonstrates the problem. By way of example [here is something I knocked up on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb4d4db7b7db8eeb645cf69950a3d632) which shows an autonomous transaction program successfully passing out a value. You need to show us something similar which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Also, what tool are you using for debugging? Oracle SQL Developer (as per your tag)?

Comment: Thanks APC 4, I have tried to sketch up the logic. Can be seen on below url. Yes I am using oracle Sql developer to debug.                                                            https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c2ddaffcc12cd7ad12e4f82ef8932bf9

Comment: @sachinzawar - in your dbfiddle it clearly shows that the output value of n is 1, so your fiddle doesn't demonstrate the problem. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and ***include code*** which demonstrates the problem on your system ***and on dbfiddle*** (because the first thing people are going to do is go to dbfiddle or sqlfiddle or wherever and try to recreate your problem, and if they can't you won't get much help).